# Is there a way to run arbitrary code on a vtech Nitro Vision?

Tags: decompilation, firmware, hardware, tools, exploit

Note: If this the wrong place to ask the question, please redirect me to the appropriate stack exchange and/or subreddit. I just figured reverse engineering is my best bet since it's kinda what I'm trying to do.

Recently, I found a vtech Nitro Vision in a thrift store for $5, in good working condition. It's a children's educational computer that uses your television as a computer monitor and speakers (plug it in with AV white and yellow), and includes a few custom-designed-for-this-thing software cartridges that you insert in the slot like with older consoles like the N64 or the Sega Genesis.

This was released in 2006 though. I imagine they did it this way (with the cartridges) because there's very little internal storage on the motherboard and it doesn't have a hard drive unlike a real desktop computer. This means that if I can find a way to either edit the code on the cartridges themselves, or connect the cartridge reader to my computer and trick it into running code from there, I could write my own programs for this neat little toy to run.

Of course, the first option is unlikely to work, since I would most likely have to get my hands on whatever card reader they used to program this thing. Second option I think is possible, but either way, I need to figure out what programming language they wrote all of this in otherwise I won't be able to use the rest of the hardware (the proprietary mouse and keyboard that came with the computer tower itself).

Speaking of which, if it helps, the keyboard is wireless and works by infrared (powered by AA batteries) and the mouse is wired to the keyboard for both function and power, with a cable that is awfully similar to the ones used with old phone lines or ethernet.

If someone feels like taking a crack at this, answer here.